# Google maps with a Yelp search overlay

Tags: search, yelp

### Original Question:  I am trying to embed a map in my site with search results overlayed on it, for instance all the bars or hospitals in the vicinity.  I know this is a common thing to do - but I am having a hard time finding example code or a tutorial on how to do this.  Can anyone provide me some pointers?

What I ended up doing was using Google maps to search on the address, then do a 'search nearby' and copy the embed code that Google provides.  Then I used innerHtml to swap that embed code out based on the checkbox clicked (whether it by bars, stores, etc) - for example:

```
    var bars       = 'embed map code from Google Maps';

            if(document.getElementById('ChkBar').checked) {
        document.getElementById('MapBlock').innerHTML = bars;
    }
```

This was a work around from trying to figure out the Yelp API and manually placing markers on the map provided from the Google maps API.

The only problem with this solution is that the embed code provided strips out the marker for the location that you did the "search nearby" for - even though it appears in the map displayed when you did the "search nearby".   I tried using custom google maps - where you are supposed to be able to add custom markers as shown here: (http://insideout.com/blog/2012/02/26/create-a-custom-google-map-for-your-blog-post-imw/) but the embed code provided by Google will not work - in fact it gives you the message:  "This map can not be embedded" - I think this is due to licensing issues.  I have tried other map sites with the same result...

This leaves me with two questions:  Does anyone know of a site that provides embed code that will display the marker for the location search around as well as markers for the locations returned from the search?  Based on what I have done the past day I think this is unlikely - but possible so worth asking.

If not - then I am left to using the yelp API and manually place markers on a google map provided by the google map API.  I have the google api figured out.  The Yelp API I am having problems with.  Does anyone know of a good tutorial or have sample code that extracts location information from a yelp search through the yelp api?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Place Library for local search.
Google Place search is very easy and work well.
Here is the link for Google documentation below.
Have a look, I think you will get your answer.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_searches